# Openly Editable Site Design

Tags: feature-request

As we hopefully go live pretty soon here I was thinking it would be really neat if we could implement an editable site, perhaps just the logo. If you've ever seen the Yale MFA website I'm imaging that on a less intrusive scale.

[Art at Yale](http://art.yale.edu/) and you'll see on the left it says:

> Page last changed by:
>
> Patricia DeChiara
>
> Background changed by:
>
> Njoki Gitahi
>
> Page editable by:
>
> Everyone

Again maybe just the logo and have it say similar so people know who changed it. Then just decide what level of reputation is needed to get to do that. (Probably fairly high to make sure its not abused or made profane)

Answer (score 4):

The photo site has a photograph of the week. We could try out a logo of the (Month?), but I don't like the idea of just letting anyone edit the site... See an example of the latest [photo weekly contest](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2657/weekly-featured-image-ongoing-contest).

Comment: Didn't know that about the Photo site but that sounds great. Does it have to be voted and approved or how do they arrange it over there? I think it should be all inclusive so everyone can get a turn not just the best designer dominating.

Comment: See http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2657/weekly-featured-image-ongoing-contest

Comment: I like this idea, perhaps even instead of a logo rotation we could just do a design showcase. Same as your photograph of the week except open to any sort of design related thing.

Comment: I like it as logo so its something specific to the forum and gives people a set challenge. Maybe we could do both though, the logo just rotating so even beginners can get in on it with possibly subpar results and then another one which is a more broad design of the week which would be more challenge oriented to produce the best possible work.

Comment: I just think it would be a good way to A. get people including beginners involved and B. showcase work that might not conform to the modern trends of good design.

Comment: I think it's an amazing idea. Why don't you open a new question and add a feature-request tag to it, Pearson?

Comment: @Yisela: I had something long long ago, at http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/8/graphic-of-the-week . But I won't stop someone if they re-post the same idea.

Answer (score 3):

ermm....I really dislike this idea :)

The horrors we'd be faced with. Design by committee is never a good thing, especially when each committee member can work autonomously.

Your example link doesn't make your case, it's horrid.

Comment: I use to think it was horrid and in a way it still is but its also incredibly interesting to see. I think the real horror in that particular case is that its usually animated gif and tiled. If we only did the logo it would be far less horrid but still be a really cool draw to add some graphic design and character to the site.

Answer (score 1):

While the idea of a community-edited site (graphic-wise) sounds philosophically great, the actual execution I think would be problematic.

First of all, no other SE site works this way, so while not impossible, such a request would be quite difficult to implement. And second, how can we guarantee the site will a) look decent enough, and b) allow new user's familiarity? Unless the changes follow a strict set of rules, I see a big problem in showing people different designs over time, as most of them could have problems identifying the site when they come back.

I strongly agree with Pearson, though. A 'logo of the month' showcase / winner would be really nice! It's not just letting any new user edit the site, it's showing our ideas and letting the community vote for the favorites, like they do in Photography :)

The only thing I'm not sure about is *how* we could change the logo, and more important *if* we are 'allowed' to do it being still in Beta. I don't know of any Beta that has a custom logo, but at the same time, we would be taking that responsibility off the hands of SE, and it sounds great for a GD site!

Why don't we **open a new question** and add the feature-request to it? (probably because of the time difference, I can't seem to contact the overlords in chat).

Comment: Well I dont know if while in Beta which is why I said when we're out of Beta. But once we're out I don't think its an issue since most other exchanges have branded their individual hub. As long as the StackExchange part remains consistent at the very top controlling the `inbox` I don't know why it would be an issue.